# Android - How to implicit intent from one app of my own to choose another 2 apps of my own?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have two apps of my own that are clone of each other just with different names. and a 3rd app that jumps between those two. by clicking on a button from 3rd app i wanna to open up app chooser and just between the 2 and jump immediately to 2nd activity not the main one.

I added this intent filter to the original two apps so it jumps to the 2nd activity

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity2"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.action.ex3.register" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Then on 3rd client app i added this to the button

```
 findViewById<Button>(R.id.reg_btn).setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent()
           intent.setAction("com.action.ex3.register") // Action for what intent called for

            startActivityForResult(intent,2)
```

note: I know that startActivityforResult is deprecated, but the lecturer still wants this method

Comment: `exported` needs to be true for other apps to be able to successfully reach that activity.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code with your package name to launch that app :

```
val launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.abc");
startActivity( launchIntent );
```